# Как отправить PUT запрос

Tags: php, yii2, http, yii, https

Использую [yii2-httpclient](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient) получилось отправить GET запрос так:

```
    $client = new Client(['baseUrl' => 'https://mysite.ru/']);
    $response = $client->createRequest()
        ->setMethod('get')
        ->setUrl('api/' . $this->model . '/' . $this->id)
        ->addHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Basic '.base64_encode("$this->user:$this->password")])
        ->send();
```

Пытаюсь отправить PUT так

```
    $client = new Client(['baseUrl' => 'https://mysite.ru/']);
    $response = $client->createRequest()
    ->setMethod('put')
    ->setUrl('api/' . $this->model . '/' . $this->id)
    ->addHeaders([
        'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization' => 'Basic '.base64_encode("$this->user:$this->password"),
    ])
    ->addContent('name', 'ahahahha')
    ->send();
```

но не получается, сервер с API отвечает

```
    Parameter <b>-----------------------100352f7324fdfd41476f7b53baf8d7d
    Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name</b> is not allowed for model <b>mymodel</b>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно реализовать PUT запрос через yii2-httpclient, спасибо.

Comment: Вот так https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient/doc/api/2.0/yii-httpclient-client#put()-detail

Comment: @AlexanderChernin вариант с использованием метода put() пробовал, выходит тоже самое. Как передать Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded с помощью этого клиента?

Comment: С `Content-Type` у вас все в порядке. Проблема в `_name`, который не подходит для модели `mymodel`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin для теста я использую Postman и когда там выбираю Body -> x-www-form-urlencoded, затем ввожу данные для обновления, то они обновляются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у меня получилось так =)

```
    $client = new Client(['baseUrl' => 'https://mysite.ru/']);
    $response = $client->createRequest()
    ->setMethod('put')
    ->setUrl('api/' . $this->model . '/' . $this->id)
    ->addHeaders([
        'Accept' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization' => 'Basic '.base64_encode("$this->user:$this->password")
    ])
    ->setData(['name' => 'ahahahha'])
    ->send();
```